# Equilateral triangle and 120° angle

Tags: geometry

[image]

P is the angle's vertex. With A,B we form an equilateral triangle on the same direction the angle's rays open up.

How can I  prove the triangle's third vertex C is always on the bisector's line?

Comment: I agree with David plus: how are the lines $\;AP\,,\,BP\;$ constructed? Or better: what is point $\;P\;$ ?

Comment: Yes, but A and B can be anywhere on those lines.

Comment: 120° angle is given, A and B points of the triangle is on the legs of the angle, the question is: C is always on the angle bisector?

Comment: Ooooh, that's *waay* another way to *correctly* write the question, @user124432. You should probably add that $\;P\;$ is the angle's vertex and that with $\;A,B\;$ we form an equilateral triangle on the same direction the angle's rays open up, Now, prove the triangle's third vertex $\,C\,$ is *always* on the bisector's line

Comment: Thanks @DonAntonio, I've corrected my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by some comments, the problem has been originally misstated. It should be: we are given a 120 degrees angle with vertex P and an equilateral triangle ABC inscribed in it, such that the vertices A and B lie on the sides of the angle and C is in its interior, as in the drawing. Show that the line PC bisects the angle APB (i.e., that the angles APC and CPB are both  60 degrees).

Proof. Consider  the quadrangle ACBP. It  is cocyclic (its vertices lie on the same circle) since the sum of the angles at its  opposite vertices  P and C is 180 degrees. Thus the angles APC and CPB are equal, since they are inscribed angles in the same circle that are facing equal segments. QED

From the proof you can see that it is enough to assume that ABC is isosceles, i.e. AC=BC, and that the sum of the angles and P and C is 180 degrees.

Comment: You seem to understand my question. Can you give me more details?

Comment: I don't get it: of course $\;\angle APC=\angle BPC\;$ It is given that they both equal $\;60^\circ\;$ ! Did I miss something here?

Comment: And anyway, how does that help to solve the problem? Oh, well: the answer's been accepted so who cares...

Comment: There seem to have been a confusion about the statement of this nice problem. I have now added to my answer a restatement. See if it's clearer now.

Comment: @DonAntonio: The diagram shows the bisector of angle $APB$, not (or only in hindsight) the line $PC$. The problem is to prove that $C$ lies on the said bisector.

Comment: I knew that all the way along, @TonyK

Comment: @GilBor, your first lines are in direct contradiction to what the OP wrote the first time and to what he hismelf re-wrote later: the angle's bisector is *first* given and thus we must prove the third vertex of the equilateral triangle $\;ABC\;$ is on it.

Comment: @DonAnonio, there is no contradiction. An angle has only one bisector. Thus, in order to show that C lies on the bisector of the angle at P, its enough to show that the segment PC bisects the angle at P...

Comment: I'm not arguing against that, @GilBor, but for the OP's original, and not explicitly edited, intention: the *equilateral triangle* was the very first thing given, *and then* one had to prove why the upper vertex $\;C\;$ is actually on the angle's bisector (or what's the same, why $\;PC\;$ is in fact the angle's bisector). For what is worth, I think your interpretation is as good as anyone's else and we just suffered, as in almost uncountable other ocassions, of another sad example of a sloppy, ill-posed question by students with *at least* high school level...

Comment: @DonAntonio: well, indeed it was a little sloppy, but on the other hand, the problem is really beautiful (in my opinion), a shiny small gem of elementary geometry of the type  I am collecting for a long time, so I am really grateful for the person who posted it and the website that enabled me to know it. Thank you all. Please keep on posting such nice problems.

Comment: I agree with you, @GilBor: it's a rather nice basic problem...and your solution is very nice (the cociclyc thing is cool). +1

Answer (score 0):

Draw two perpendicular lines from C to PA and PB, and the intersecting points are D and E, as shown below:

[image]

What we need to prove is that △CDA≌△CEB, therefore CD=CE, and since any point on an angle bisector has equal distance to the two side of the angle, we finish proving that C is on the angle bisector of ∠APB.

It is easy to get that CA=CB, ∠CDA=∠CEB=90∘. We need to get one more condition, which is ∠CAD=∠CBE.

Apparently, ∠CAB=∠CPB=60∘, therefore C、A、P、B are concyclic. Thus, ∠ACP=∠ABP. We can see that ∠CAD=∠CPA+∠ACP=60∘+∠ABP=∠CBA+∠ABP=∠CBE.

Answer (score -1):

Call $\;M\;$ to the intersection point of $\;PC\,,\,AB\;$ , and observe that

$$\Delta APM\sim\Delta BPM\;\;\text{by s.a.s., since applying the angle bisector theorem we get}$$

$$\frac{AM}{MB}=\frac{AP}{PB}\;,\;\;\text{on the triangle}\;\;\Delta APB$$

This means $\;PC\perp AB\;$ (why?) , so both $\;\Delta CBP\;,\;\Delta CAP\;$ are right triangles (and, in fact, golden ones $\;30-60-90\;$).

Now just remember that an angle's bisector is the locus of all points on the plane that are equidistintant from both angle's rays.

Comment: $PC\perp AB$??? What if $A\approx P$? Perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: @DavidMitra, I don't know what $\;A\cong P\;$ means in this geometric setup.

Comment: Anyway,  $\;PC\perp AB\;$ follows from $\;\Delta APM\sim\Delta BPM\implies \angle AMP=\angle BMP=90^\circ\;$, since $\;\angle AMB=180^\circ;$ by construction.

Comment: What if the point  $A$ is close to (or even equal to) the point $P$? The angle between $AB$ and $PC$ will then be approximately (equal to) $60^\circ$.

Comment: $\;A,B\;$ are points each on *different* rays of the angle, @DavidMitra. This follows at once from the original, incorrect wording of the problem.

Comment: @DavidMitra, anyway: assuming each of $\;A,B\;$ is on a different ray, the simmilarity in my answer leads unavoidably to $\;PC\perp AB\;$ .

Comment: Apparently, $\triangle APM$ need not be similar to $\triangle BPM$. What are the two congruent sides referred to in your answer? It seems you're assuming $AP$ is congruent to $BP$; but I don't think that was given.

Comment: @DavidMitra, no that wasn't given, and that's not what I wrote: I wrote $\;\frac{AM}{MB}=\frac{AP}{PB}\;$ ...

Comment: I can't make any sense of this at all.

Comment: You don't understand and thus you downvote, @TonyK ?

Comment: @DonAntonio, it's you that doesn't understand the question. For instance, $PC$ is not (in general) perpendicular to $AB$. What I meant was, I can't for the life of me see how you _did_ interpret the question.

Comment: No, it's you @TonyK that don't understand the OP first posted the question one way and then he changed it and, from the given drawing and what he wrote, I addressed the question as it was. Just read the comment the OP wrote to my doubt about what he asked. Anyway, if you don't understand then why do you downvote?

Comment: My proof of the facts is there: either it is correct or it is wrong. If it is correct then the mentioned lines are perpendicular. Period. With that the proof is complete. Address this and either point the mistake or else acknowledge you misunderstood.

Comment: Oh, now you're cross.

Comment: That must be a new expression: "you're cross"...I wonder what that means in Central Europe...And yet you don't address the mathematical point, @TonyK